# Como guardar todos los datos de una consulta de MYSQL en un array de PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

gracias por la ayuda que me pueda aportar.
tal vez mi pregunta sea un poco simple pero no he podio resolverlo.

hago una consulta a la base de datos a través de PHP, esta consulta puede tener de 1 o varios valores de resultado, quiero guardar los resultados en un array para despues verificar si un valor esta en el arreglo con array_search(). pero hasta a hora solo he logrado que se guarde la primera fila, es decir solo me guarda el primer valor que tiene la base de datos y no los otros. me podrían orientar de como se debe hacer.

esta es la consulta a la base de datos:

```
function consulta_usuario_permisos($id_user)
    {
        $conexion = conectar();
        $consulta = "SELECT id_modulo FROM usuario_modulo WHERE id_usuario = '$id_user'; ";
        $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion,$consulta)or die("No se pudo ingresar recuperar usuario: ".mysqli_error($consulta));
        return $resultado;
        $conexion->close();
    }
```

despues obtengo los valores a través de este código, pero al imprimirlo solo me arroja el primer valor, el primer renglón.

```
$per= consulta_usuario_permisos($id_usr);
$permisos = mysqli_fetch_array($per);

print_r($permisos);
```

Espero pueda recibir ayuda de los expertos. les agradezco de antemano que compartan su conocimiento con todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque `mysqli_query()` devuelve un puntero hacia los datos, es decir, no son los datos en sí. Entonces, hay que mover ese puntero para obtener cada fila.

Generalmente ese puntero se mueve dentro de un bucle y se va imprimiendo o guardando los datos en una variable. Estás obteniendo una fila precisamente por eso, porque tu llamada a `fetch` sin bucle mueve el puntero hacia la primera fila, pero no se sigue moviendo para obtener las otras filas posibles.

Es mejor aplicar eso en la función. Por ejemplo:

```
function consulta_usuario_permisos($id_user)
    {
        $conexion = conectar();
        $consulta = "SELECT id_modulo FROM usuario_modulo WHERE id_usuario = '$id_user'; ";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die("No se pudo ingresar recuperar usuario: ".mysqli_error($consulta));
        #Array para guardar los datos
        $mData=array();
        #Dado que fetch_array devuelve dos tipos de datos
        #usamos un método más específico
        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) {
            #Aquí se irá llenando el array con cada fila
            $mData[]=$fila;
        }
        #No debe ir nada después de return   
        $conexion->close();
        #Nótese que lo que se retorna es $mData
        return $mData;
    }
```

Y luego, en el contexto de la llamada haces simplente esto:

```
$per= consulta_usuario_permisos($id_usr);
#Deberías tener los datos ya en $per
print_r($per);
```

### Recomendaciones

1. Considera no usar `die`  para control de tu código, el uso de `die` no te facilita controlar lo que ocurrió con la llamada a la función. Es mejor controlar con otro tipo de información, como una clave `status` en un array o algo así, o simplemente verificando si la respuesta está vacía. En esa misma línea, considera no mostrar mensajes de error internos del manejador, es información valiosa para los hackers.
2. Considera blindar tu código usando consultas preparadas. El código actual es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: Muchas gracias probare lo que me dices. gracias por decirme como funciona mysqli_querry, no tenia idea.

Comment: @ChristianMagaña ten en cuenta que en la llamada a la función no necesitas aplicar de nuevo `fetch`. Lo ideal es que la función te devuelva todos los datos como ya haría cuando actualices el código. Entonces en la llamada bastaría esto: `$per= consulta_usuario_permisos($id_usr);` Ya los datos estarían en `$per` y los puedes testear con  `print_r($per);` o con `var_dump($per);`